# Можно ли как-то отследить ошибку приложения?

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, shell

Google chrome выдает ошибку, редко, но выдает:

```
dns_probe_finished_no_internet
```

Интернет активен при этом. Спасает только перезагрузка.
Можно ли как-то мониторить, и при возникновении этой ошибки запускать shell?

Comment: Что Вы хотите промониторить?

Comment: можно если использовать в браузере chrome:/inspect